# How to extract a sub-array from two arrays with high performances?

Tags: javascript, arrays, json, performance

I have two arrays of JSON objects :

- one contains about 60.000 elements, which represents my reference dataset. Each JSON inside owns a key and some other attributes. Please note that the key might be not uniq in the array.
- another one contains a various number of elements (at least a few thousands). Each JSON inside owns a key (that is also defined in the first array), and some other attributes.

e.g. :

```
let refarray = [{key : 1, attr1 : 'aze', ...}, {key : 1, attr1 : 'zer', ...},{key : 2, attr1 : 'ert'},...]
let otherarray = [{key : 1, attr2 : 'wxc', ...}, {key : 3, attr2 : 'xcv'},...]
```

I simply need to extract from refarray all elements whose key exists in otherarray.

For the moment I'm using loadash as following :

```
let newarray = _.filter(refarray , function(d) { return _.findIndex(otherarray , function(s) { return s.key=== d.key;}) >= 0});
```

But it takes between 3 and 15 seconds, which is far too long. Any quickest solution is welcome. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

You may try caching the keys of `otherarray` and then filter `refarray`. I tried a small sample (although I tried on `node` and not browser) and it was taking a little over 100 ms:

```
let refarray = []
let otherarray = []

for(let i of Array(60 * 1000).keys())
  refarray.push({ key: 1 + (i % 1200) })

for(let i of Array(1000).keys())
  otherarray.push({ key: i + 1 })

console.time('cache')
let cache = _.uniq(_.map(otherarray, n => n.key))
const inCache = n => cache.indexOf(n.key) !== -1

let newArray = _.filter(refarray, inCache)

console.timeEnd('cache')
console.log(refarray.length, otherarray.length, newArray.length);
```

Comment: wow impressive, performances are just gerat with this method. Could you please explain a little bit what's different with my own method ?

Comment: Essentially, there is no difference, except I mapped out key values into an array and just using `Array.prototype.indexOf`. I have been in this situation before and found `indexOf` works faster than many other implementations.

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the amount of duplicate keys, solution by Emil S. Jørgensen might not be optimal enough. I would go with iterating over distinct values of 1st array:

```
d2 = Date.now();
var distinct = [];
refarray.forEach(function(item) {
    if (distinct.indexOf(item.key) < 0) {
        distinct.push(item.key);
    }
});
console.log('Results:',otherarray.filter(function(item) {
    return distinct.indexOf(item.key) > -1;
}));
console.log('Milliseconds to filter:', Date.now() - d2);
```

Comment: According to my tests, your solution seems to be performant-equivalent to Harsh Gupta's one. Nethertheless thank you.

Answer (score 0):

[Array.prototype.filter](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) with [Array.prototype.some](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) should be the fastest approach.

```js
//Default ref
var refarray = [{
  key: 1,
  attr1: 'aze'
}, {
  key: 2,
  attr1: 'zer'
}];
//Default other
var otherarray = [{
  key: 1,
  attr2: 'wxc'
}, {
  key: 3,
  attr2: 'xcv'
}];
//Padding ref
while (refarray.length < 10 * 1000) {
  refarray.push({
    key: 5,
    attr1: 'aze'
  })
}
//Padding other
while (otherarray.length < 60 * 1000) {
  otherarray.push({
    key: 6,
    attr2: 'aze'
  })
}
console.log('Size of refarray:', refarray.length);
console.log('Size of otherarray:', otherarray.length);
var d = Date.now();
console.log('Results:',refarray.filter(function(a) {
  return otherarray.some(function(b) {
    return b.key == a.key
  })
}));
console.log('Milliseconds to filter:', Date.now() - d);
```

Comment: Thanks for your proposition. However I just implemented it, and performances are worst...

Comment: @MrFlo Are you certain this is the part that slows you down? Maybe it is the rendering or some other factor that takes performance? How fast does my snippet run by itself in the browser?

Comment: The snippet you provided runs well. It takes less than one second to be fully run. On my side I make some console.log with the date before and after each compute, and it gave me a less good result for your code... Could it be due to the complex structure of each JSON element ?

Comment: @MrFlo Maybe the `console.log` is slowing it down because it needs to render? Try appending to a string variable and only log at the end of execution.

Comment: I don't think so, as I tried other propositions, and they work better. Moreover even with no console.log, it's still slow...